# Rubymine creating shortcut in Desktop Error

Tags: software-installation

I've installed Rubymine, but it is in a different drive.

When I tried to create a desktop icon for Rubymine it showed the following error:

```
unable to locate suitable startup script in /meadia/data/installedfolder/RubyMine/bin
```

Is it an issue with installation?

1. What is the suggested folder to install the software? [extracting and running scripts]
2. If it is installed in another drive I need to mount it before running the application. So how to manage that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if your drive is mounted before you start the application. I suggest you to mount your drive permanently.
2. Check the path of your shortcut:

   `/meadia/data/installedfolder/RubyMine/bin` sounds wrong to me, try `/media/data/installedfolder/RubyMine/bin` instead.
3. If this doesn't work, try to create your shortcut using Rubymine itself. Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Create Desktop Entry...</kbd>

   It won't create the shortcut on your desktop. But after that you can find Rubymine on the Dash. When you open it, you will see the Rubymine icon at the sidebar. You can right-click <kbd>Lock to Launcher</kbd> to keep it there.

Comment: I've edited your answer and removed the `/opt/`-preference. Maybe I've got a bit overboard deleting it. If you think it should belong in your answer, you can find your old version when you click the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/539989/edit)-link below your answer and edit it back.